# unable to solve strptime() issue even after trying all the formats

Tags: python, strftime, strptime

I'm using the following code:

```
data['Input_volTargetStart'][1]>time.strptime(data['Dates'][1], "%d %b $y")
```

When I try to run it, I get this error:

> ValueError: time data '04-Jun-99' does not match format '%d %b $y'

I have tried possibly all combinations but am unable to get the result for this conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually put the dashes ('-') as part of the format, i.e "%d-%b-%y".

Answer (score 1):

This is what you'll need.

```
from datetime import datetime

a = "04-Jun-99"
frmt = datetime.strptime(a, "%d-%b-%y")
print(frmt)

>>1999-06-04 00:00:00
```

Implement that example into your code to get proper output.