# strptime error like this time data '01–MAY-21' does not match format '%d-%b-%y'

Tags: python, strptime

I try code like this,it occurs error.
I don't know which part the below is faulty code?
I cannot use the code as the first sample below. What did I do wrong?

```
from datetime import datetime

required_format="%d-%b-%y"
a="02–MAY-21"

print(a)

aaa = datetime.strptime(a, required_format)
print(aaa)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-aea82823c657> in <module>
      7 
      8 
----> 9 x_date = datetime.strptime(str_date, datetime_format)
     10 print(x_date)

D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\mybase\lib\_strptime.py in _strptime_datetime(cls, data_string, format)
    566     """Return a class cls instance based on the input string and the
    567     format string."""
--> 568     tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
    569     tzname, gmtoff = tt[-2:]
    570     args = tt[:6] + (fraction,)

D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\mybase\lib\_strptime.py in _strptime(data_string, format)
    347     found = format_regex.match(data_string)
    348     if not found:
--> 349         raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
    350                          (data_string, format))
    351     if len(data_string) != found.end():

ValueError: time data '02–MAY-21' does not match format '%d-%b-%y'
```

meanwhile , I try code from [unable to solve strptime() issue even after trying all the formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362296/unable-to-solve-strptime-issue-even-after-trying-all-the-formats)

```
from datetime import datetime

required_format="%d-%b-%y"
a = "02-MAY-21"
frmt = datetime.strptime(a, required_format)
print(frmt)
```

it works well, this is result 2021-05-02 00:00:00

I think both are pretty much the same, there are few different parts in code but it doesn't even matter.

Comment: @sophros Nothing truly odd about it, just the difference between a `-` and a `–` ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your original string has U+2013 EN DASH characters as the separators:

```
>>> x ='02–MAY-21'
>>> hex(ord(x[2]))
8211
```

The format string you're trying has regular dashes (U+002D).

```
>>> f = '%d-%b-%y'
>>> hex(ord(f[2]))
'0x2d'
```

You may wish to normalize the en dashes to regular dashes and use a format pattern with a regular dash.

```
>>> datetime.strptime(x.replace("\u2013", "-"), "%d-%b-%y")
datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 2, 0, 0)
>>>
```